# Masked TextBox Input Align Left

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, controls, textbox

I have a masked textbox on my winforms application where if a user clicks inside of the masked textbox, the cursor will start out in that location. For example, if they click in the middle of the masked textbox there will be a blinking cursor in the middle. How can I get the cursor behavior to be such that it will default at the left-most portion of the masked textbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hook into the click event and then do something like this:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.maskedTextBox1.Click+=new EventHandler(maskedTextBox1_Click);
    }

    private void maskedTextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.maskedTextBox1.Select(0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

into the click event :

```
maskedTextBoxname.SelectionStart = 0;
```

(with this when you click on the maskedtextbox the cursor will appear at the left)

```
maskedTextBoxname.SelectionStart = maskedTextBoxname.Text.Length;
```

(with this when you click on the maskedtextbox the cursor will appear at the last char written, if the maskedtextbox is empty the cursor will appear at the left)